# Htaccess regex to exclude everything except one string

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have done this: http://rubular.com/r/AHI15Tb4ju, and it match the second url (http://gamempire.localhost.it/news/tomb-pc), but I want to exclude that url and match everything that do not have the word "news/" inside (but at the same time end in the way that I have specified).

How to do that?
Basically, i want to match only the third url (http://gamempire.localhost.it/tomb-pc).

Thanks!

Comment: huh? What are your current htaccess rules?

Comment: You want to grab the entire URL or just the part after the last forward slash?

Comment: @PanamaJack this is my current htaccess: `RewriteRule ^(.*)-(?:pc|ps2|ps3|ps4|xbox-360|xbox-one|xbox|wii-u|wii|psp|ps-vita|ds|3ds|iphone|ipad|android|playstation)(.*)$ /$1$2 [NC,R=301,L]`

Comment: @CAustin i want to grab everything, like in the rule written in my last comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use a rule like this:

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/news/
RewriteRule -(?:pc|ps2|ps3|ps4|xbox-360|xbox-one|xbox|wii-u|wii|psp|ps-vita|ds|3ds|iphone|ipad|android|playstation)(.*)$ / [L,R]
```

Since I didn't know any action part I just redirected these matching URI patterns to `/` that you can change according to your need.

Comment: sorry had a typo, just fixed it. Try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
^((?!news).)*-(?:pc|ps2|ps3|ps4|xbox-360|xbox-one|xbox|wii-u|wii|psp|ps-vita|ds|3ds|iphone|ipad|android|playstation)(.*)$
```

It should be noted that I tried to modify your original pattern as little as possible, assuming you also needed the (.*) at the end even though it appears that this is unnecessary for your purposes, and would match strings such as 
"http://gamempire.localhost-pc.it/tomb" and "http://-pcgamempire.localhost.it/tomb".